# Getter for arbitrary property of object

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, getter

I have a class that looks like this

```
export default class {
  constructor () {
    this.store = {}
  }

  setX (x, y) {
    this.store[x] = y
  }
}
```

How would I define a getter on `this.store` to return `0` when getting an undefined value?

Let me give an example:

`setX('a', 1)` would set `this.store['a']` to `1`

then `this.store['a']` would return `1`, as expected.

But `this.store['b']` would return `undefined`, but I want the getter to return `0` instead (and maybe call `setX('b', 0)`, not sure yet).

I know I can use `Object.defineProperty` to define a custom getter, I just can't wrap my head around how to access an arbitrary, not yet defined property of the `store` object.

Is this at all possible or do I have to use a work-around like this?

```
getX (x) {
  return this.store[x] || 0
}
```

I would like to avoid that, because `this.store[x]` seems so much cleaner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How would I define a getter on `this.store` to return `0` when getting an `undefined` value?

Unless you can anticipate all possible property names you want to support and define getters for them, to do that you need a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) with a [`get` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get), which is new as of ES2015 (and cannot be polyfilled). Proxies are expensive in performance terms, use them only when you really need them.

Example:

```js
class Example {
  constructor () {
    this.store = new Proxy({}, {
      get(target, property) {
        return property in target ? target[property] : 0;
      }
    });
  }

  setX (x, y) {
    this.store[x] = y;
  }
}

const e = new Example();
console.log("Setting a");
e.setX("a", "foo");
console.log("a = " + e.store.a);
console.log("b = " + e.store.b);
```

Of course, if you make `store` private, you could enforce access only through a `getX` method on the object, which would avoid the use of a proxy at the expense of defining `setX` and `getX` on a per-instance basis (for now, [private data is coming](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)):

```js
class Example {
  constructor () {
    const store = {};
    this.setX = (x, y) => {
      store[x] = y;
    };
    this.getX = x => {
      return x in store ? store[x] : 0;
    };
  }
}

const e = new Example();
console.log("Setting a");
e.setX("a", "foo");
console.log("a = " + e.getX("a"));
console.log("b = " + e.getX("b"));
```

Comment: Isn't it preferred to use `hasOwnProperty()` instead of `in`?

Comment: @Adelin: As a blanket statement? No, not at all. It depends entirely on what you're doing. Here, we're getting a property from an object, which will traverse the prototype chain, so using an operation that traverses the prototype chain makes sense.

Comment: That's really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: (nevermind this comment, I just had to add a getter for the whole store object as well) As a follow-up: how would this work with class methods/does it at all? Like if I have a class method `add (x, y) { this.setX(x, this.getX(x) + y) }`, this doesn't seem to work, all I get is undefined.

Comment: @Decay42: That will work just fine. Of course, if you wanted the result as a return value from `add`, you'd need to modify `setX` to return it, and modify `add` to return it. (Or you could do `add(x, y) { var result = this.getX(x) + y; this.setX(x, result); return result; }` but having `setX` return the value that was set is simpler, and consistent with how `=` works.)